# Cut broccoli reconstruction

Tags: modeling

I would like to recreate the object in the pictures (don't ask) attached below in Blender and haven't found a satisfactory method yet. How would you guys go about this? Do you have any spontaneous ideas? The goal should be an almost 1:1 reconstruction, at least in terms of proportions/dimensions.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Blender has an addon called Add Curve: Sapling Tree Gen that will build trees based on values that you specify. After applying the results, they can be converted to pure geometry. Afterwards, you could prune it so that only the trunk remains, then cut it short right where it begins branching, and you might have something like what's in the picture.

Comment: You could try recreating the base shape with meta balls, then sculpting the finer details. You could even try photogrammetry since it's quite a complex shape, then just retopologize and sculpt to clean up your mesh.

Comment: Try Qlone on iOS. Exporting is pro, but purchase would be permanent.

Comment: You could try photogrammetry. While Blender won't do it by itself, there are free solutions which can do it, and export a mesh which can be modified afterwards (cleaning, texturing...) in Blender.

Comment: I know this won't be popular, but perhaps spending a few bucks to buy a broccoli model might be cheaper and easier :).